# How to create manage package using developer edition with Dev Hub enabled

Tags: managed-package, package, unmanaged-package, developer-edition, dev-hub

I have already enabled my `Dev Hub` on my developer edition and using this environment to create scratch orgs with `Visual Code`. Now we want to create a managed packaged from this developer edition but while creating one salesforce is showing following message

[image]

[image]

As I am new to salesforce I am not aware what to do in this case to create a managed package. Unmanage package has a big disadvantage of not updating itself hence we want to create a manage package and deploy it to production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You will need to create a second Developer Edition org to act as your packaging org. A single Developer Edition is not permitted to be both Dev Hub and packaging org.

Comment: so how do i transfer all my code , custom objects and fields on the new developer edition ?

Comment: @Hunt You can use any tool to manage Salesforce metadata, including SFDX, CumulusCI, Force.com Migration Tool, Workbench, etc.

Comment: I am using visual code to manage code but in order to connect to another developer edition I will be needing scratch org so not sure how to do that with visual code :(

Comment: @Hunt You can connect multiple Developer Editions to Salesforce DX in Visual Studio Code. The `sfdx force:auth:web:login` command will establish a connection.

Comment: Yeah I am able to do so and eventually created a managed package , now the last question is will my manage packaged get installed on the client's production version ?

Comment: You *can* install a managed package on a production Salesforce org. It is not an automatic process.